# Do I say "a damaged and a healthy model" or "a damaged and a damaged models"?

Tags: grammatical-number

"(...) representing a healthy and a damaged models."

Other examples: "Compute the subspace distances for each mode between the healthy and (the) damaged models.",

"Transfer function comparison between complete and nominal models."

Is there any difference if I put the definite article the before the terms?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to say "a damaged and a damaged models".

Comment: A comparison between a damaged and a healthy model. No s. Or: A comparison between damaged and healthy models. Either a, no s, or use the a and leave out the a.

Answer (score 0):

The first one should be:

> (...) representing a healthy and a damaged model.

You use the singular version of 'model' because you use the article, 'a', before your two examples of models ("a healthy and a damaged").

The reason why you use the plural 'models' in your "complete and nominal models" example is because you exclude the article, 'a'.